# Linux Raspi OS, DNS lookup fails despite internet connection with OpenVPN private VPS

Tags: linux, networking, dns, raspberry-pi, openvpn

Setup :
I have a raspi OS (v10) with a Sixfab IOT hat for NBIOT connections. The Sixfab works over PPP0, which is a USB link.

Issue:
I have DNS issues with my LTE connection when the module is already connected and working.
My internet connection is established and I test using the following parameters.

```
ping 8.8.8.8
Returns ICMP packets

ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

I don't get why my DNS wont connect so I went and manually assigned DNS network to google.

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
*** File editor
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

On checking my routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         192.168.174.233 0.0.0.0         UG    304    0        0 wlan0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.13       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.13       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     225    0        0 wwan0
192.168.174.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     304    0        0 wlan0
```

If my routing table did not work I would not be able to ping. I tried changing the default route to wwan0 interface using  `sudo IP route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wwan0` but that just makes the internet unreachable ( makes sense as it has to go through the point protocol)

My route lists

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip route
default dev ppp0 scope link
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.13 dev tun0
10.8.0.13 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.14
10.64.64.64 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 10.200.143.221
169.254.0.0/16 dev wwan0 scope link src 169.254.198.107 metric 225
```

Just on a side note, the 10.8.0.1 is set by an OpenVPN client that I am running to connect to a server, that is a private VPS(On testing i see that the openVPN when disconnected my DNS issues are resolved).

Narrowing the issue:
Seems like the OpenVPN client has some kind of issue that does not automatically skip it, to go and resolve on the public network.

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of troubleshooting, i had dig deeper into the OpenVPN configurations.

On the Server End on OpenVPN-server configuration file add the following line, this makes sure that the DNS option is set even after connecting to the private network i use 8.8.8.8 that is google DNS

```
# DNS Push
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```